# Chat Contact List VB.NET and MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I'm making a chat system for my work and I'm having trouble to find a way to display users and their status.

So I have a Form called Chat Client

There I have `Panel1(Left)`  and `Panel2(Right)`

In `Panel1` I have to get every user listed in my database

```
Select [first_name] + ' ' + [Name] As 'Contact', [Status] From dbo.TableUsers
```

This gives following:

```
[green image] [contact name]   (if someone is logged in (status online))
[Orange image] [contact name]   (If someone is logged in (status away))
[Red image] [contact name]  (If someone is not logged in (Status offline))
```

How can I create a subscript that gives me all the users listed in the table with an image before the name showing their status?

Comment: I would look into service broker. You can create a dependency in your application. Anytime a table changes for example refresh your data...  Find more here https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&ei=KZnVVt2qDOOnjgS3sbjgAQ&q=service+broker+example&oq=service+broker+e&gs_l=mobile-gws-hp.1.1.0l5.1590.8026.0.10646.19.18.0.8.8.0.939.4446.0j6j5j3j1j0j1.16.0....0...1c.1j4.64.mobile-gws-hp..2.17.2950.3.1mMoFrCMNVo#q=service+broker+vb.net+example

Comment: ?? that's not an answer to my problem.
I need something that can create a list with a statusimage and the name.

(Green.img) Joseph Smith
(Orande.img) Katy Johnson
(red.img) Bob Newland
(red.img) Edwin Cooper

and so on...     i have a table which has 2 columns. 1st one is [Name]  and 2nd [Status] (which returns Online, Away or Offline)

Comment: `This subscript in VB.NET will run every minute to refresh how can I do this` sounds like you needed help How to get it to me... The other info is what you have already. Maybe you need to explain more of ***what you don't have*** Also you are right it's not an answer hence it's a comment. Your question isn't clear enough to help you. You could create a user control that would house a label for a name and a picturebox for the image. Create this new control for ever user that came back from your query and show them in a flowlayoutpanel...

Comment: I added my question, thanks for clearing that one out for me..  What is the best way to make a usercontroll with this flowlayoutpanel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself :)

i used e TableLayoutPanel with 2 columns and i filled it up with this:

```
While UserData.Read
            If UserData("Status").ToString = "Online" Then
                Dim newPictureBox As New PictureBox
                newPictureBox.Image = My.Resources.greenchat
                newPictureBox.Visible = True
                newPictureBox.Width = 30
                newPictureBox.Height = 30
                newPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
                newPictureBox.Name = UserData("Username").ToString & "Pic"
                ChatContactList.Controls.Add(newPictureBox)

                Dim newLabel As New Label
                newLabel.Text = UserData("Voornaam").ToString & " " & UserData("Achternaam").ToString
                newLabel.Name = UserData("Username").ToString & "Lab"
                newLabel.Font = New Font("Microsoft sans serif", 12)
                newLabel.Height = 30
                newLabel.AutoSize = True
                newLabel.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
                newLabel.Visible = True
                ChatContactList.Controls.Add(newLabel)

            ElseIf UserData("Status").ToString = "Afwezig" Then
                Dim newPictureBox As New PictureBox
                newPictureBox.Image = My.Resources.orangechat
                newPictureBox.Visible = True
                newPictureBox.Width = 30
                newPictureBox.Height = 30
                newPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
                newPictureBox.Name = UserData("Username").ToString & "Pic"
                ChatContactList.Controls.Add(newPictureBox)

                Dim newLabel As New Label
                newLabel.Text = UserData("Voornaam").ToString & " " & UserData("Achternaam").ToString
                newLabel.Name = UserData("Username").ToString & "Lab"
                newLabel.Font = New Font("Microsoft sans serif", 12)
                newLabel.Height = 30
                newLabel.AutoSize = True
                newLabel.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
                newLabel.Visible = True
                ChatContactList.Controls.Add(newLabel)

            ElseIf UserData("Status").ToString = "Offline" Then
                Dim newPictureBox As New PictureBox
                newPictureBox.Image = My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("redchat")
                newPictureBox.Visible = True
                newPictureBox.Width = 30
                newPictureBox.Height = 30
                newPictureBox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
                newPictureBox.Name = UserData("Username").ToString & "Pic"
                ChatContactList.Controls.Add(newPictureBox)

                Dim newLabel As New Label
                newLabel.Text = UserData("Voornaam").ToString & " " & UserData("Achternaam").ToString
                newLabel.Name = UserData("Username").ToString & "Lab"
                newLabel.Font = New Font("Microsoft sans serif", 12)
                newLabel.Height = 30
                newLabel.AutoSize = True
                newLabel.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
                newLabel.Visible = True
                ChatContactList.Controls.Add(newLabel)

            End If
        End While
```

Answer (score -1):

I have seen your resolution, I understand wrongly. anyways its good you get resolution of this task.

Comment: i'm new with vb.net so i have some question with this:   Why With (nolock) ??   and   what do i have to do with web/WCF ??

Comment: This is a recomendation not a solution to the OP question.

Comment: Add field in your table with Status 'varbinary'  (in MS SQL) and below link may help more
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842065/how-to-save-and-retrive-picturebox-image-to-sql-server-database-varbinarymax-c