# VB.NET how to check if a form with a specific text is opened

Tags: vb.net

I have a form called Chatbox that i use for each contact that is clicked.

I do this with following code:

```
    Dim ChatBoxWindow As New Chatbox
    labelhandlename = DirectCast(sender, Label).Name
    ChatBoxWindow.Name = labelhandlename
    Chat_WindowList.Add(ChatBoxWindow)
    ChatBoxWindow.Show()
```

What i want to do is check ---

```
    Sub Chatbox(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)

    labelhandlename = DirectCast(sender, Label).Name
    Dim thisOne = Chat_WindowList.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = labelhandlename)

    If Chatbox.name = labelhandlename Then

        thisOne.Focus()

    Else

        Dim ChatBoxWindow As New Chatbox
        ChatBoxWindow.Name = labelhandlename
        Chat_WindowList.Add(ChatBoxWindow)
        ChatBoxWindow.Show()

    End If

End Sub
```

Whats the best way to do this? (note: chatbox.name doesn't work)

Comment: Just don't lose your reference to the instance.  Add it to, say, a List(Of ChatBoxWindow) so you can find it back later.  Remove it from the list with an event handler for its FormClosed event.

Comment: It looks like you already have a list of them, so to find one should be simple: `Dim thisOne = Chat_WindowList.FirstOrDefault( function (x) x.Name="something")`  or thereabouts

Comment: @Plutonix So than i have to do     Thisone.activate    or what?

Comment: `thisOne.Focus()` should bring it into view.

Comment: @visualvincent edited the code above but my sub gives me an error on chatbox.name

Comment: What's the error??? EDIT: Aren't you supposed to get rid of the `If`-statement? The `thisOne` variable already holds the ChatBoxWindow you're looking for.

Comment: Do `If thisOne IsNot Nothing Then` instead.

Comment: perfect ;) thank you very much.  maybe you can help me with another issue http://stackoverflow.com/q/35841444/5601492

Comment: @Visualvincent Maybe a little question. when i close a chat window, how can i delete that one from that list?

Comment: What list?? I don't see any list in your code. **EDIT:** Oh wait...

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
For Each myForm As Form In Application.OpenForms
    If myForm.Name = "something" Then
        ' Do something.
    Else
        ' Do something else.
    End If
Next
```

> [Application.OpenForms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.openforms(v=vs.110).aspx) gets a collection of open forms owned by the application.

But make sure to take a look at [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751554/application-openforms-count-0-always), as Plutonix suggests.

Comment: When i do this i get the following error:  Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Chatbox(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)

    labelhandlename = DirectCast(sender, Label).Name
    Dim thisOne = Chat_WindowList.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = labelhandlename)

    If thisOne IsNot Nothing Then

        thisOne.Focus()

    Else

        Dim ChatBoxWindow As New Chatbox
        ChatBoxWindow.Name = labelhandlename
        Chat_WindowList.Add(ChatBoxWindow)
        ChatBoxWindow.Show()

    End If

End Sub
```

thanks to @VisualVincent AND @Plutonix

Comment: Okay, removing the form when closing. Do you target .NET 4.0 or higher? If so you could do like this: `AddHandler ChatBoxWindow.FormClosed, Sub() Chat_WindowList.Remove(ChatBoxWindow)`.

Comment: I did this @visualvincent and does the same :):

    `Sub Chatbox_Closing(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles Me.Closing

        Dim thisOne = Chatsys.Chat_WindowList.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Name = ChatRxUsername)

        Chatsys.Chat_WindowList.Remove(thisOne)

    End Sub`

Comment: Skip the variables and stuff in the `Closing` sub. Do it in one line: `Chatsys.Chat_WindowList.Remove(DirectCast(sender, ChatBox))`