# Crop image and save it in database using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm following a tutorial on [Image Cropping with resizing using vb.net](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27061/Image-Cropping-with-Image-Resizing-Using-VB-NET) . Everything works well, But instead of saving it 
on the hard disk. I want to save it on my database(SQLServer).

This is the code of saving on a disk

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cropSaveBtn.Click
        Dim tempFileName As String
        Dim svdlg As New SaveFileDialog()
        svdlg.Filter = "JPEG files (*.jpg)|*.jpg|All files (*.*)|*.*"
        svdlg.FilterIndex = 1
        svdlg.RestoreDirectory = True
        If svdlg.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            tempFileName = svdlg.FileName           'check the file exist else save the cropped image
            Try
                Dim img As Image = PreviewPictureBox.Image

                SavePhoto(img, tempFileName, 225)
            Catch exc As Exception
                MsgBox("Error on Saving: " & exc.Message)
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function SavePhoto(ByVal src As Image, ByVal dest As String, ByVal w As Integer) As Boolean
        Try
            Dim imgTmp As System.Drawing.Image
            Dim imgFoto As System.Drawing.Bitmap

            imgTmp = src
            imgFoto = New System.Drawing.Bitmap(w, 225)
            Dim recDest As New Rectangle(0, 0, w, imgFoto.Height)
            Dim gphCrop As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(imgFoto)
            gphCrop.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality
            gphCrop.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality
            gphCrop.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High

            gphCrop.DrawImage(imgTmp, recDest, 0, 0, imgTmp.Width, imgTmp.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

            Dim myEncoder As System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder
            Dim myEncoderParameter As System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter
            Dim myEncoderParameters As System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters

            Dim arrayICI() As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders()
            Dim jpegICI As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageCodecInfo = Nothing
            Dim x As Integer = 0
            For x = 0 To arrayICI.Length - 1
                If (arrayICI(x).FormatDescription.Equals("JPEG")) Then
                    jpegICI = arrayICI(x)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
            myEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality
            myEncoderParameters = New System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameters(1)
            myEncoderParameter = New System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 60L)
            myEncoderParameters.Param(0) = myEncoderParameter
            imgFoto.Save(dest, jpegICI, myEncoderParameters)
            imgFoto.Dispose()
            imgTmp.Dispose()

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Function
```

I want it to save the picture to SQL Server 2008 (Image data type) together with my two data just like this

```
   Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("dbo.uspAdd", cn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstname", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtName.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@lastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = txtSurname.Text
        'add insert picture code here   
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Save Record New record Successfully")
    End Using
```

And now i'm stuck for almost 8 hours finding ways on how to fix this.Can anyone help me to solve this. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this helps; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842065/how-to-save-and-retrive-picturebox-image-to-sql-server-database-varbinarymax-c or you could convert to base64 and back...?

Comment: @Lectere Can you help me to use that in line with my code?

Comment: First, consider **not** saving image data, but the path to the image file.The [image data type was deprecated long ago](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx), so you should be using VarBinary instead using a byte array.  Dont save as a B64 string - that will be much larger than need be.  Also using empty catch blocks is a very bad idea

Comment: @Plutonix, Thanks for giving me the idea, Can you help me to build a code in line with my code in order for me to move on.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31370711) shows the general steps, but as I said, it is often better to save the file somewhere and just reference it.  You can avoid having to thumbnail (== crop???) the image and throwing away data.

Comment: @Plutonix Can you make your code simplier sothat I can follow it easily. I find it a bit complicated.  And please include to save the file somewhere and just reference it. I want to learn from you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest converting the image to Base64 and then storing it as a string.

Then when you want to get the image back you need to convert it back from Base64 to an image.

You can convert an image to Base64 using this code:

```
  Public Function ConvertImageToBase64(ByRef img As Image, ByVal format As System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat) As String
        Dim ImgStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
        img.Save(ImgStream, format)
        ImgStream.Close()
        Dim ByteArray() As Byte = ImgStream.ToArray()
        ImgStream.Dispose()
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(ByteArray)
    End Function
```

(http://www.dailycoding.com/posts/convert_image_to_base64_string_and_base64_string_to_image.aspx)

And to convert it back to an image you can use this code:

```
 Public Function ConvertBase64ToImage(ByVal base64 As String) As Image
        Dim img As System.Drawing.Image
        Dim MS As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream
        Dim b64 As String = base64.Replace(" ", "+")
        Dim b() As Byte
        b = Convert.FromBase64String(b64)
        MS = New System.IO.MemoryStream(b)
        img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(MS)
        Return img
    End Function
```

(http://snipplr.com/view/27514/vbnet-base64-to-image/)

Now you can basically add the image as a string, like this:

```
Dim Base64Bitmap As String = ConvertImageToBase64(img, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Image", SqlDbType.VarChar, Base64Bitmap.Length).Value = Base64Bitmap
```

Comment: ,thanks for the answer. When i tried the above code, I have an error in this line `Dim Base64Bitmap As String = ConvertImageToBase64(img, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)` saying that `'img' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.`

Comment: Did you declared your image as "img", like I see in your example you  declared your image object as "src" or "imgTmp". try using "src" or instead of img.